# What is the difference between using "onclick = 'google.com'" for a div and making <a href = "google.com">?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm having a really difficult time using flexbox to position my links. It just seems to not work (as an example, see the code below. The links should be below "Link 2" yet they're below "Link 1"). Perhaps it doesn't work because I need to make links within divs within links for my code. However the exact same CSS seems to work if I just make everything a div. If I could make all the links just divs with the "onclick" function that links to the page I want it to go to, positioning would be so much easier.
So is there any difference between making a linked  tag using "onclick" vs. using ? Will it make any difference on my website?

```html
<a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">Link 1</a>
<div id = "container"><a id = "mainlink" href = "https://www.google.com/">Link 2</a>
   <div id = "content">
      <a href = "https://www.images.google.com/">Images</a>
      <a href = "https://www.news.google.com/">News</a>
      <a href = "https://www.maps.google.com/">Maps</a>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
   #container{
      display: inline;
   }
   #content { 
      display: flex;   
      flex-direction: column;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `<div>` with a click event instead of a real link will:

- Not be accessible to people using a screen reader (it won't be announced as a link)
- Not be accessible to people navigating with a pointing device (e.g. people who can't operate a mouse (perhaps due to arthritis)) (the div won't be in the tab order).
- Not appear as links to search engines (which could impact SEO)

---

Start by structuring your links with semantic markup. Then sort out your layout with flexbox instead of `display: inline`.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="//example.com/">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="//example.com/">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="//example.com/">Link 2a</a> </li>
        <li><a href="//example.com/">Link 2b</a> </li>
        <li><a href="//example.com/">Link 2c</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

@Quentin has effectively handled the *why*.

You can make an `<a>` act just like a `<div>` with a simple:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That won't have the desired effect though. It will put links 1 and 2 one above the other instead of side by side

Comment: @Quentin Further modifications are up to you. If you can do it with a `<div>`, you can do it with an `<a>`. You say "If I could make all the links just divs"; I've told you how to do that.

Comment: @ceejayoz Quentin didn't say  "If I could make all the links just divs". He is not the questioner

Comment: But I need the display for the links to be inline for them to be next to each other

Comment: @AnikaMisra If you know how to do that with DIVs, you can do it with A tags too. The CSS I've provided makes them act just like DIVs.

Comment: But I can't have the display be block because I need the display to be inline for the links.